# Can't resolve module Error Setting Up TypeScript 2 / Angular 2 / Webpack 2 for the First Time

Tags: angular, webpack, typescript2.0, tsconfig, ts-loader

I'm trying to setup TypeScript Angular Webpack project for the first time, but I've been hit by an avalanche of errors which I'd like some help to resolve.

I've tried to compare my project against an angular-cli project, but I'm just not seeing what's missing.

I've tried downgrading typescript, @angular modules, and webpack; no joy. I've used specific package versions because we do that at work for stability.

This feels more like a problem where ts-loader needs to be told where to find things, as the app itself just boilerplate.

In tsconfig, some settings are missing because the tsconfig.json documentation says they are defaulted, e.g. target=es5, module=commonjs but I'm happy to try anything. Others are there because I wanted to see what they did; I'm happy to drop those too if necessary.

Below, I've included (a) a sample of the errors received (b) package.json, (c) tsconfig.json and (d) webpack.config.js (e) main.ts

Sample errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/platform-browser-dynamic' in '/Users/Ian/Desktop/TestFolder/Bare/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js 13:0-47
 @ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/platform-browser' in '/Users/Ian/Desktop/TestFolder/Bare/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser'
 @ ./~/@angular/platform-browser/index.js 13:0-295
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/forms/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/forms' in '/Users/Ian/Desktop/TestFolder/Bare/node_modules/@angular/forms'
 @ ./~/@angular/forms/index.js 13:0-709
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/core/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/core' in '/Users/Ian/Desktop/TestFolder/Bare/node_modules/@angular/core'
 @ ./~/@angular/core/index.js 13:0-2208
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/@angular/http/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index' in '/Users/Ian/Desktop/TestFolder/Bare/node_modules/@angular/http'
 @ ./~/@angular/http/index.js 13:0-406
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "BareNg2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "w": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.6",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "7.0.4",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.28",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "listFiles": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "traceResolution": true,
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ]
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts' ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          visualStudioErrorFormat: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

/src/main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode }         from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule }              from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

/src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I removed the "strictNullChecks" from tsconfig.json and the errors reduced to the 4 above.

Comment: I tried blowing away node_modules and doing npm install as some posters on GitHub had suggested, but that didn't work. Same errors as above.